# Readers-Writers problem with pthreads resulting in only 1 reader

Tags: c, pthreads, producer-consumer

A task I have is to create a solution to the readers-writers problem with posix pthreads. I spawn 3 readers and 1 writer.

The task spec asks to add values to the queue 2 at a time (writers). The readers dequeue one at a time (when there exists a value in the queue). The queue has been tested and works.

The problem I have is when running the program, it results in only 1 reader thread actually reading *most of the time*. Sometimes repeated execution will result in all 3 readers being used. But most of the time its just 1 reader being used. I am not sure why this strange behavior occurs.

Thanks in advance.

```
Expected (Sometimes): 
TID: -684419328
TID: -684419328
TID: -673929472
TID: -673929472
TID: -694909184
TID: -694909184
...
```

```
Actual (Sometimes): 
TID: -684419328
TID: -684419328
TID: -684419328
TID: -684419328
TID: -684419328
TID: -684419328
...
```

```c
pthread_cond_t qServiced = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t qElement = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

```c
#include "rw.h"
#include "queue.h"

queue* q; 

void* reader()
{
    int serviced = 0; 
    int x; 

    while(!fin)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        counter++; 

        while(isEmpty(q))
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&qEmpty);
            pthread_cond_wait(&qElement, &mutex); e 
        }

        printf("TID: %d\n", (int)pthread_self());

        num* n = dequeue(q); //Take one task 

        printf("Num1: %d\n", n->num1);
        printf("Num2: %d\n", n->num2);

        serviced++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&qServiced); //Signal that task has been serviced
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

Comment: For `pthread_cond_wait(&qEmpty, &mutex);`, who is signalling the qEmpty condition?

Comment: @user7176709 I see, added. Not sure if in the right place. But issue still stands :(

Comment: I am not sure why would you write this: 
`while(isEmpty(q))
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&qEmpty);
            pthread_cond_wait(&qElement, &mutex); 
        }     '
In the `writer` thread.
Why to check for the empty condition in writer thread?

Comment: @user7176709 My mistake I edited the wrong part of code in stackoverflow. The issue still stands. Perhaps I am causing a race condition somewhere?

Comment: What scheduler are you using?

Comment: @stark I am using posix pthreads

Comment: @technik Did you fix the visibility problem with total_tasks? That problem is causing your writer to never terminate. Fix that problem and your writer will terminate.

Comment: the syntax for a posix thread function is: `void *threadFunction( void *arg )`    The correct statement to exit a thread is `pthread_exit( int *status );`

Comment: in the writer thread function, this statement: `exit(0);` will cause the whole program to exit.  Should use: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: regarding the statements: `#include "rw.h"` and 
`#include "queue.h"`  The contents of these two homegrown header files need to be posted

Comment: where is the function: `isFull()`?\

Comment: regarding: `srand((unsigned) time(&t));`  The code should not be trying to both set some local time_t variable AND return the time_t.   Suggest: `srand( (unsigned) time( NULL ) );`

Comment: regarding: `pthread_cond_wait(&qElement, &mutex); e`  What is that 'e' on the end of the line.  BTW: the code does not need any of the `pthread_cond_wait()` nor the `pthread_cond_signal()`  Suggest removing ALL of them and using only the `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()`

Comment: the posted code has the mutex locked (almost) all the time by the first thread that executes.  This is not a good idea.  Suggest using `nanosleep(1000)` (or something similar) to give the other threads a chance to run while the mutex is NOT locked

Comment: @user3629249 I will begin to fix these issues. I have also noticed an issue, my writer thread actually does manage to exit when i change it to `pthread_exit(NULL);` but my 3 readers never finish/ terminate and join ends up waiting infinitely. I am not sure why.

Comment: OOPS, did you edit the posted code?  Almost all of it has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

The following proposed code is only for the 'read()' thread, but should give you an idea as to how to write the threads.

```
void* reader( void *arg )
{
    int *fin = (int*)arg;

    int serviced = 0; 

    while( !(*fin) )
    {
        printf("TID: %d\n", (int)pthread_self());

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        counter++; 
        num* n = dequeue(q); //Take one task 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if( n )
        {
            printf("Num1: %d\n", n->num1);
            printf("Num2: %d\n", n->num2);
            serviced++;
        }

        else
        {
            printf( "no queue entries available\n" );
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

note that the mutex is only locked when the thread is performing actions that could result in a 'race' condition.

The proposed code assumes (since the queue handling code was never posted) that `dequeue()` returns NULL if the queue is empty

Note: when no queue entry available, the thread sleeps for a while

This assumes that the main() function, passes the address of 'fin' as a parameter in the call to `pthread_create()`

Answer (score 1):

Threads get scheduled by the scheduler in a one of the scheduling mechanism. But as a programmer, you should assume that it can be any random way and code.

By saying "random way",  I mean all threads can get scheduled once in the course of the program or only one thread gets scheduled in the entire course.

**Thread may get scheduled in a random way.** I hope this answers your question.

If you want a specific way by which the execution should happen (example: All threads read once before a thread read for the second time) then you have to code accordingly. You can use mutex, semaphores, condition signals, flags and a combination of all these to achieve this.